# Search on website conditional of changing different cells

Tags: html, vba, excel, stock

I am currently trying to write a code in VBA, the purpose of this code is in general:

- Type input into a cell "A" in a defined range.
- Left from this particular cell (within the range) i want different information from a website-search to be printed next to the input-cell "A".

More specifically I want to write a code, where I can type in specific stock tickers in a column (ie. "IBM"), and when I do this, a procedure begins, which goes to finance.yahoo.com, collects different information about this specifik stock (ie. "International Business Machines"), and prints this information "to the right" of the cell where i typed the stock ticker in the first place.

The goal is to be able to type in 20-30 stock tickers, and make it retrieve the information for every ticker and print it to the right of those stock tickers.

I have already figured out how to type in one ticker in a specific cell, and make it retrieve the desired data from the website, and then print it into specific cells "to the right" of the input-cell.

My challenge now, is to be able to do this for a large range of cells below the first input-cell.

My code as of now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range("Sheet1!$A$2").Row And _
Target.Column = Range("Sheet1!$A$2").Column Then
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
  IE.Visible = False
 IE.navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AiMiBWm16z_q5Ai0SlNb3jaiuYdG;_ylu=X3oDMTBxdGVyNzJxBHNlYwNVSCAzIERlc2t0b3AgU2VhcmNoIDEx;_ylg=X3oDMTBsdWsyY2FpBGxhbmcDZW4tVVMEcHQDMgR0ZXN0Aw--;_ylv=3?s=" & Range("Sheet1!$A$2").Value 'This types in the value from my input-cell into the website, so i get directed to the webpage for this particular company.
  Do
   DoEvents
  Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
  Set Doc = IE.document
  Dim Name_001 As String 'Info-cell with name of the company
  Dim Ticker_001 As String 'Info-cell with current price of the company
   Name_001 = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("title")(0).innerText)
   Ticker_001 = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top sigfig_promo_1")(0).innerText)
 IE.Quit
 Dim Nam_001 As Variant
 Dim Tic_001 As Variant
  Nam_001 = Split(Name_001, "(")
  Tic_001 = Split(Ticker_001, " ")
  Range("Sheet1!$B$2").Value = Nam_001(0)
  Range("Sheet1!$C$2").Value = Tic_001
End If
```

End Sub

- "Sheet1!$A$2": The input-cell
- "Sheet1!$B$2": First output cell for the name of the stock ticker.
- "Sheet1!$C$2": Second output cell for the current price of the stock ticker.

Right now my code only works for one row, i want it to work for all the rows beneath the current input-cell:

I hope my question is clear, and that you can help me with my problem (I am not allowed to post any pictures, so I cant show you my work book, however I have tickers in column "A", name in column "B" and price in column "C").

Thanks in advance - Juhlers.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code: (1) changed sheet name; (2) Removed anchored row ($2) and replaced with 'Target.Row'; (3) Added Error Trap - sometimes get error; (4) Changed Cursor to 'Busy' since it takes a few seconds.  Try The following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim IE          As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc         As HTMLDocument
Dim Name_001    As String 'Info-cell with name of the company
Dim Ticker_001  As String 'Info-cell with current price of the company
Dim Nam_001     As Variant
Dim Tic_001     As Variant

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    If Target.column <> 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
        Application.Cursor = xlWait
        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AiMiBWm16z_q5Ai0SlNb3jaiuYdG;_ylu=X3oDMTBxdGVyNzJxBHNlYwNVSCAzIERlc2t0b3AgU2VhcmNoIDEx;_ylg=X3oDMTBsdWsyY2FpBGxhbmcDZW4tVVMEcHQDMgR0ZXN0Aw--;_ylv=3?s=" & Range("Stocks!$A" & Target.row).value 'This types in the value from my input-cell into the website, so i get directed to the webpage for this particular company.
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Name_001 = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("title")(0).innerText)
        Ticker_001 = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top sigfig_promo_1")(0).innerText)
        IE.Quit
        Nam_001 = Split(Name_001, "(")
        Tic_001 = Split(Ticker_001, " ")
        Range("Stocks!$B" & Target.row).value = Nam_001(0)
        Range("Stocks!$C" & Target.row).value = Tic_001
        Application.Cursor = xlNormal
    Exit Sub
Error_Trap:
    Application.Cursor = xlNormal
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```